# How can I fix this bad drywall patch

Tags: drywall, ceiling

I recently had my ductwork replaced and since my home doesn’t have an attic, the ceilings had to be opened up. However when they closed the drywall back up and painted, it started to become very lumpy / droopy. What are my options for fixing this?

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean when you say **"it started to become"**? Your question implies that it was *not* lumpy and droopy when they finished the job, but now has become that way... which could be a huge problem. If the repaired area was *always* like that, well that's a bad repair job; if it was fine and then *became* like that, you've got immediate issues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start out by sanding the seams and lumpy areas to determine if it's just a lousy taping job. If so, rip off the old tape and redo. If the drywall is droopy, you'll have to attach it to the joists with more screws. If the paper is separating from the drywall surface, you'll have to replace the drywall with some new drywall.

Comment: Agree but honestly that isn't horrible, yet.   I wouldn't create an absolute mess in a living space until I had some other work to do there.   At the very very least this is screwing, sanding, mudding, sanding, painting and probably more than that.